# Where is external js file in html stored? Can I

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Sorry, I don't have a good understanding of the web, but:
When you load in an external script file into an html document, where does it hold or cache that file? It doesn't put it in the index.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="name_of_file"></script>
</head>
.....
```

I ask because I'm working with node.js, and I'm wondering if I list an external script file under my index.html page, I can send the javascript file to the client.

Comment: this is totally unclear.  are you asking where the file lives on your server?

Comment: `src` tells the browser to get the file and store it somewhere in the hard disk (of client machine) . Then the browser parses it. After that, The browser creates a group of objects (functions are also objects). Then, when a function is  executed, it lives in RAM and use CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the browser will recognize the "src"="http://xxx/xx.js" of your script tag,and check if the resources(identified with URI:"http://xxx/xx.js") has cached in browser local cache dir(every browser has its own dir)
- if the file exist and cache is not expired,the browser will directly load this file,otherwise browser will download the script file,and execute them when download finish.

Answer (score 0):

This question has no good answer. A JavaScript program can be located anywhere on a server, It's just linked to with `<script src=SCRIPT></script>` Where SCRIPT is the relative or absolute path to the .js file. Check out [This](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) site for more info.

Answer (score 0):

It's wherever the file is being served from.  With what you've given and default setup, the file will be in the same directory as your index.html file